# How to use Observable in angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing, angular2-services

I am using Guards in my application. If I do a refresh, the page does not load again an jumps on #.

The problem is the Guard. On refresh it does not have the loginUser.

In my case I do not know how to use the observable:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyComponentGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private _userService: UserService) { }
    //on refresh it returns false because the loginUser is null
    canActivate() {
        return this._userService.isUserinGroup(UserGroup.CALL_CENTER);
    }
```

my service:

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {

private loggedInUser: User = null;

constructor(private _httpService: HTTPService) { }

//this is called in root component
public loadUser() {
        this._httpService.getAuthenticationUser()
            .subscribe(this.setLoggedInUser.bind(this));
    }

private setLoggedInUser(user: User) {
    this.loggedInUser = user;
}

public getLoggedInUser(): User {
    return this.loggedInUser;
}

public isUserLoggedIn(): boolean {
    return this.loggedInUser != null;
}

public isUserinGroup(group: UserGroup): boolean {
    //here is the problem the user is on refresh null
   if (!this.loggedInUser) {
        return false;
    }

    for (var userGroup of this.loggedInUser.authGroups) {
      //  if in group return true
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

how can I do here a async call?

Answer (score 3):

Change the guard to be async:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyComponentGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private _userService: UserService) { }
    //on refresh it returns false because the loginUser is null
    async canActivate(): Promise<boolean> {
        return this._userService.isUserinGroup(UserGroup.CALL_CENTER);
    }
```

Then change your service to be async as well:

```
public loggedInUserPromise: Promise<User> = null;

constructor(private _httpService: HTTPService) { }

//this is called in root component
public loadUser() {
    if (!this.loggedInUserPromise) {
        this.loggedInUserPromise = this._httpService.getAuthenticationUser().toPromise();
    }
}

public async isUserinGroup(group: UserGroup): Promise<boolean> {
   if (!this.loggedInUserPromise) { this.loadUser(); }

   const user: User = await this.loggedInUserPromise;
   if (!user) {
        return false;
    }

    for (var userGroup of user.authGroups) {
      //  if in group return true
    }
    return false;
}
```

I removed the `setLoggedInUser` and `getLoggedInUser` functions as they aren't really needed and you should be using `get` and `set` directly on the property if you do come to need additional code there.

Comment: @AluanHaddad do you mean in the `isUserinGroup` method? You would could equally write it without `async` by returning `true` or `false` from a `then` callback, no `Promise.resolve` needed. I don't think I agree in any case as I think the flattening you get from `async` makes the code cleaner.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the `await` I do agree it is cleaner as you have written it.

Comment: @Duncan thx for your answer, but this is not working. On laoding the application is in a freeze mode. I can do nothing. I add everywhere a async where I call the isUserinGroup method.